# ssreflect: elementary algebraic simplification

Tags: coq, ssreflect

Having this lemma

```
Lemma my_lemma n : n %/ 4 * 4 + n %% 4 * 5 - n %% 4 * 4 = n.
Proof.
  (* ? *)
  (* n %/ 4 * 4 + n %% 4 = n. *)
  symmetry. apply: divn_eq n 4.
Qed.
```

How can I convert `n %% 4 * 5 - n %% 4 * 4` to `n %% 4`? Then in will be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this problem, the idiomatic approach in ssreflect is to do rewrite using all the theorems about arithmetic at hand.  This requires a little search.  I suggest you use the `Search` command extensively.

The first hurdle is that your formula contains `(A + B - C)` which is not the same thing as `(A + (B - C))`, because of the special behavior of truncated subtraction.  To convert between the two, you can look for a theorem.  I typed the following `Search` Command.

```
Search (_ + _ - _).
```

Among the theorems that were listed I was satisfied with `addnBA` (associativity between addition and subtraction), but this lemma has a side condition, which I want to prove first.  So I use the following rewrite command.

```
rewrite -addnBA; last first.
```

Here I want to factor out the multiplication in the comparison.  I look for a theorem containing this pattern with the following `Search` command.

Search _ (_ * _ <= _ * _).

Please note the first `_` pattern in this `Search` command, it is important, if you don't include it, only some of the interesting theorems are listed, and the one we want won't appear.  The one I want is `leq_mul2l`

I perform this proof in the following manner:

```
by rewrite leq_mul2l orbC.
```

After `rewrite leq_mul2l` the statement is an `_ || _` statement (boolean disjunction), and the right hand side is obviously true modulo computation (in `ssreflect`), by commuting this boolean disjunction, I make so that the goal can be solved directly without further ado.

Now, we come to distributivity of multiplication over subtraction.  Here search commands are more tricky to use, because distributivity laws are treated with a keyword.

```
Search (_ * (_ - _)).
```

Does not give any useful result, but there is useful documentation in `ssrnat` about naming patterns.  It tells us that when subtraction is a secondary operation, then `B` is likely to appear in the theorem name.  Here we want a theorem that about natural numbers, so it should be in `ssrnat`, so I attempt the following.

```
Search "B" in ssrnat.
```

This tells me that there are some theorems whose statement relies on concepts like `left_distributive` and `right_distributive`.  You can understant this concepts by printing them.

```
Print right_distributive.
```

In the long run, you tend to remember the names of theorems you use often, so in my case, I knew I was going to use `mulnBr`, because the subtraction is on the right of a multiplication, and we are working with natural numbers.  The math-comp library is designed with a strong attention to regularity of naming.

So we can now finish the modification in the following manner:

```
rewrite -mulnBr muln1.
```

and you can finally apply the lemma you wanted to apply.

The full script is as follows:

```
Lemma my_lemma n : n %/ 4 * 4 + n %% 4 * 5 - n %% 4 * 4 = n.
Proof.
symmetry.
rewrite -addnBA; last first.
  by rewrite leq_mul2l orbC.
rewrite -mulnBr muln1.
apply: divn_eq n 4.
Qed.
```

Comment: `rewrite -leq_mul2l` gives an error:

`((_ == 0) || (_ <= _))
does not match any subterm of the goal`

We need to use `rewrite leq_mul2l`.

Comment: @Yves What a great writeup, I added the link to it to the Mathcomp wiki: https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/wiki/Search#examples (I hope you don't mind)

Comment: Also, a tad shorter proof: `rewrite -addnBA; last by rewrite leq_mul2l orbC.
by rewrite -mulnBr muln1 -divn_eq.`

Comment: I am still upset that we cannot use just `Search` to find all the relevant theorems.  It has been annoying me for a long time, but I still don't see how to get a single tool that will assist newcomers in a satisfactory way.